# Spinner wont dissapear on webview load - android

Tags: java, android, progress

I'm trying to set a progress spinner (in andorid) to disappear once the webview has loaded but cant get it to work at all, the spinner appears using onPageStarted but doesn't disappear using onPageFinished does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //spinner.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);

        // Enable Setup Webview
        // WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
         mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
        // myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
                spinner.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // do your stuff here
                spinner.setVisibility(WebView.GONE);
            }
        });

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overwriting old webViewClient.

// Remove this because you already set one above which is responsible for showing and hiding progressbar.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Afraid the spinner still remains on the webview, even when it's fully loaded.

Comment: That's pretty much it, I'm not trying to do anything else

Comment: I believe thats a reason for issue, don't know why downvote

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome, did the trick, learning more every day!!